# how to create for function in R for small dataset?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

my data set is like this

```
blood pressure :            127 127 127-146 127-146
serum          :200-219      2   11   3       12
                220-259      3   88   23      100
                >259         7   56   11      11
```

how to create for loop in my test

```
prop.test(2,11,p=p0,correct = FALSE)
prop.test(3,88,p=p0,correct = FALSE)
prop.test(7,56,p=p0,correct = FALSE)
prop.test(3,12,p=p0,correct = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: If you need to do this several times, create a small function `f1 <- function(v1, v2, p) {prop.test(v1, v2, p = p, correct = FALSE)]`